# Erlang/OTP ./configure failure Open Solaris

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, erlang, solaris

was running `./configure` for OTP14BO3 on Open Solaris. part of the output is here:

```
Ignoring the --cache-file argument since it can cause the system to be erroneously configured
Disabling caching
checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for ld... ld
checking for GNU make... yes (gmake)
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking ERTS version... 5.8.4
checking OTP release... R14B03
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating make/emd2exml
configure: configuring in lib
configure: running /bin/sh '/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib/configure' --prefix=/usr/local  --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib
configure: creating ./config.status
configure: configuring in snmp/.
configure: running /bin/sh '/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib/snmp/./configure' --prefix=/usr/local  '--prefix=/usr/local' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib/snmp/.
checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking for perl... perl
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating mibs/Makefile
configure: configuring in common_test/.
configure: running /bin/sh '/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib/common_test/./configure' --prefix=/usr/local  '--prefix=/usr/local' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib/common_test/.
checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating priv/i386-pc-solaris2.11/Makefile
configure: configuring in diameter/.
configure: running /bin/sh '/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib/diameter/./configure' --prefix=/usr/local  '--prefix=/usr/local' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib/diameter/.
checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/ginstall -c
checking how to create a directory including parents... /usr/bin/ginstall -c -d
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/app/diameter.mk
config.status: creating make/i386-pc-solaris2.11/rules.mk
configure: configuring in erl_interface/.
configure: running /bin/sh '/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib/erl_interface/./configure' --prefix=/usr/local  '--prefix=/usr/local' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib/erl_interface/.
checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details.
configure: error: /bin/sh '/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib/erl_interface/./configure' failed for erl_interface/.
configure: error: /bin/sh '/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software/otp_src_R14B03/lib/configure' failed for lib
```

part of the contents of the `config.log` is:

```
configure:2455: gcc -Ae -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
:0:1: error: missing '(' after predicate
conftest.c:10:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:2461: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
```

its saying that there is a missing header file. How can i go around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a syntax error somewhere in the source, so your header file is probably there anyway, GCC is just not that smart sometimes and will throw you an unrelated error.

Some googling revealed [this](http://www.dev-eth0.de/couchdb-on-opensolaris-part-1-erlang/). Apparently you have to muck around a bit. Have you given it a try?